# Cannot install Laravel 4 package

Tags: laravel, migration, package, composer-php

I'm trying to install the following package:

[Laravel 4 Auth token](https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token)

But when I try to run the migration I got the following error

```
there is nothing to migrate
```

(while there should be). When I go to the vendor folder, the package folder exists, but it is empty. Furthermore, I've successfully published the config of this package.Could someone please explain to me why can't I run the migration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following command

```
php artisan migrate --package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token
```

to migrate for your [package (tappleby/laravel-auth-token)](https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token). When you had run

```
php artisan migrate
```

you got the message `there is nothing to migrate` is because you are running your own migration file. So, It's say nothing to migrate! For more about migration please read on [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations).